# Why we can replace ab=(ab)^-1

Tags: abstract-algebra

Why we can replace $ab=(ab)^{-1}$

I saw prove of if every element is its own inverse then the group is abelian.

And there is equality like this:

$a·b = (a·b)^{−1} =b^{−1}·a^{−1} = b·a$

I dont understand that first equality what is the reason why we can write this?

Comment: It is simply because $ab$ is an element of the group and this element has the property to be its own inverse.

Comment: Yes, what you've written seems to utilize the premise three times.

Comment: @Tucker could u explain what u mean because im new in abstract algebra and i dont get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If every element $g$ of a group $\mathcal{G}$, is its own inverse then if $g\in\mathcal{G}$, we can immediately conclude $g=g^{-1}$. One of the properties of a group is that it is closed under the binary group operation. Given $a,b\in\mathcal{G}$, we know $ab\in\mathcal{G}$. Also, we know that $ab$ is its own inverse, which explicitly means that $ab$ and $(ab)^{-1}$ are equal.

$$
ab=(ab)^{-1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $ab$ is an element of the group, it is its own inverse, thus $ab=(ab)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

It is given that every element is its own inverse, i.e if $a$ is an element in $G$ then its inverse (say $a^{-1}$ ) is  $a$. Since G is a group $$ ab \in G~~ \text{for a,b } \in G.$$
Hence by hypothesis its inverse should be equal to $ab$.